# In the Roslyn unit test projects where is $(xunitVersion) variable set?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have noticed that in the .csproj files for the unit test projects for the Roslyn source there are references to xUnit components have versions set to properties such as $(xunitVersion). Where are values for these properties set? They don't seem to be set in the project files themselves and I also looked in Roslyn.sln. I am on the master branch of Roslyn using dev studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those properties are being defined in `build\Targets\Packages.props`. This file is then being imported to other files via import directive.

For example: `src\ExpressionEvaluator\Core\Test\ExpressionCompiler\ExpressionCompilerTestUtilities.csproj` which references `$(xunitVersion)` imports `build\Targets\SettingsSdk.props` which in turn imports `Settings.props` which imports `Versions.props` which imports `Packages.props`.